# Why is my Docker image not being pushed to Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a Docker image that I'd like to push to Docker Hub:

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
mattthomson/hadoop-java8   0.1                 d9926f422c14        11 days ago         857.9 MB
```

```

I've run `docker login`, logged in as mattthomson, and run `docker push mattthomson/hadoop-java8:0.1`.  This takes a while, showing a progress bar of the upload.

However, it seems not to have worked.  If I run `docker pull mattthomson/hadoop-java8:0.1` from another computer, I get "Tag 0.1 not found in repository mattthomson/hadoop-java8".  The images doesn't show up [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mattthomson/hadoop-java8/), either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you docker push again, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried a number of times before this went through successfully.  I was misled by the fact that the upload was failing partway through, without displaying an error message, just a timestamp.  The error code was non-zero.

Comment: I pushed to docker hub and the tag panel shows size 0. I tried many times without change anything and just build && push and finally it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had to confirm my email address so my repositories show up on docker hub. Simple but didn't notice at first.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this when my Docker Hub organisation had reached its limit on the number of private repositories I was allowed to create (and I also got an email from Docker Hub about reaching this limit).

To solve the problem I upgraded my Docker Hub subscription to allow more repositories.

It would be nice if the error message from Docker Hub contained some hint to the cause.